# Font for sections, subsections and subsubsection titles (in scientific thesis)

Tags: fonts

I've seen in some questions ([Fonts for technical reports](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5534/fonts-for-technical-reports) and [What font types are good for a technical document?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51/what-font-types-are-good-for-a-technical-document)) that there are many answers to the "what types of font should I use".

Since there is **no** school template nor policy for thesis writing, I'm thinking about using something like this (which is heavily influenced by the KOMA script bundle for LaTeX):

[image]

[image]

I'm pretty satisfied with the Chapter title, the inspirational quote and the drop cap.  What I would like to know is what type of fonts can I use ---that is in harmony with the complete text and chapter title--- for the *section*, **subsection** and **subsubsection**.  Please keep in mind that the numbering must be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing Serif and Sans-Serif, in my opinion, works in a web context, but looks a bit off in this case.

I don't feel you need to use different fonts for the titles, the chapter name looks nice because it's serif and it's readable, and mainly because it just looks consistent with the rest of the text. The sans-serifs in the subsections work inversely, they cut the reading flow.

I'd consider using the same font and playing with size and weight. Can't get more harmonic than that :)

For example:

[image]

Comment: Great advice!  When you say playing with size and weight, I can imagine the higher the section, the larger the font.  What about the weight?  Should I always use bold?

Comment: This is quite personal, but I'd probably go for larger non bold for Section, smaller bold for subsection and small non bold for subsubsection. Let me see if I can create a quick sample..

Comment: I've been playing around with it, and the *subsubsection* can only be as large as the normal text size (otherwise the *section* is just too large).  So, I have LARGE *section*, Large *subsection* and *normalsize* subsubsection.  I'm guessing since I have normalsize for the subsubsection, it should be bold, right?